# multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, multiclass-classification

I want to build an ml model, which can when given a text input, can predict predefined tags or labels for the text. I already built one such model, but the problem with that is that it only predicts correct labels when a particular keyword is present in the text. **For example** - TEXT - "How to crack an interview?". LABELS PREDICTED - "Interview, Fresher". *BUT*, If TEXT - "How to clear hr round of xyz company, what questions the can ask?". ***Either it will predict some irrelevant label or no label at all***.  [My model is very similar to this model](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/predicting-movie-genres-nlp-multi-label-classification/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you overfitted.
I would advise you to get more data if you can and more importantly use a pre-trained model to encode the words to vectors. See for example the answer to [this question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267169/how-to-use-pre-trained-word2vec-model)